# want to receive customer reply sms to asp application using mvayoo

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

```
string no = TextBox3.Text;
string message = TextBox4.Text;
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://api.mVaayoo.com/mvaayooapi/MessageCompose?user=sssh@gmail.com:56321&senderID=TEST SMS&receipientno="+no+"&msgtxt=" + message + "&state=4");
HttpWebResponse Resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
System.IO.StreamReader respStreamReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(Resp.GetResponseStream());
string responseString = respStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
respStreamReader.Close();
Resp.Close();
Response.Write("sent sucessfull....");
Label3.Visible = false;
```

this is my sms send code... i don't know how to receive the reply sms on my asp application.. who could help me. thanks in advance....

Comment: no one don't know this ah?...............

Comment: they given reply sms api url is below...   can we get reply by this.......? please sugges me for this.................................................                 http://api.mVaayoo.com/mvaayooapi/MessageReply?user=sssh@gmail.com:56321&senderID=TEST SMS&receipientno=9******3&sdtime=start time&edtime=end time